Error when starting react-native app in expo
My react-native has this error when i try to run in it in expo go:
(node:15876) [DEP0044] DeprecationWarning: The util.isArray API is deprecated. Please use Array.isArray() instead.
Android Bundling failed 13895ms C:\Users\asisg\Desktop\react_native_crash_course\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js (945 modules)
error: app(auth)_layout.jsx: C:\Users\asisg\Desktop\react_native_crash_course\app(auth)_layout.jsx: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins
It was fine up until i implemented appwrite for backend stuff but the errors don't have any message saying that the appwrite stuff is the problem.
Here is the error expo go app on my phone:
I tried reinstalling expo and it worked fine.
I also tried to reinstall native-tailwind but this message popped up:
14 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 10 high, 1 critical)
To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix
Run npm audit for details.
I've run npm audit multiple times and still shows vulnerabilities
